# How to configure webpy and MySQL on OpenShift

Tags: python, mysql, web.py, openshift

I want to know how to deploy [webpy to-do example](http://webpy.org/src/todo-list/0.3) on openshift. Here is an [official webpy example](https://github.com/openshift/OpenShift-webpy-example) showing how to deploy a webpy app on openshift, but this example does not deal with mysql. Can anyone show me a demo deploying the webpy to-do example on openshift? Thanks.

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/zhangzhensong/webpy_openshift_mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Create a python application:

```
rhc app create -a webpy -t python-2.7
```

Add this upstream webpy repo

```
cd webpy
git remote add upstream -m master https://github.com/openshift/webpy-example.git
git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master
```

Then push the repo upstream

```
git push
```

[See here more](https://github.com/openshift/flask-example)